# Octal to Decimal conversion of number

Tags: python, math

I want to convert an octal number into a decimal one. Why am I getting 6 as an output instead of 83?

```
import math

def octalToDecimal(octalNumber):
    decimalNumber = 0
    i = 0
    while (math.floor(octalNumber) != 0):
        rem = math.floor(octalNumber) % 10
        octalNumber /= 10
        decimalNumber += rem * 8**i
        ++i
    print(decimalNumber)

octalToDecimal(123)
```

Comment: Also, quite trivially, you can convert any base to decimal using `int(str(num), base)`. In this case, `int(str(num), 8)`.

Comment: Internally, python's integers are binary, not "octal" or "decimal". These are just string display conventions. So, `123` isn't octal, in fact that number is `"0o173"` in python's string representation of octal. I don't see how this function is supposed to work.

Comment: @tdelaney so what does it mean to say that "123, being an octal representation of a real number, has a decimal representation of 83"?

Comment: @JordanG - When python compiles `octalToDecimal(123)`, that `123` is a literal - a string representing a number. By python syntax rules, that string is a decimal representation of a binary integer number - and that's what python creates. You could use `0o123` for octal or `0x123` for hexadecimal. In all of these cases, you get an `int`, which holds a binary integer (zeros and ones in memory). Once python parses these string representations, they all end up creating the same thing and they have no knowledge of which representation they came from.

Comment: This function just gets the binary integer and its kinda strange that it would actually represent an octal number needing the processing you show. Its possible, of course. Maybe you have some oddball protocol. But extremely uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write i+=1 instead of ++i,theres no such operator as ++ in python